# moment.js isBetween() method to use Aus date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I know how to format my dates using `moment.js`, but when I am reading the docs on the `isBetween()` method, it states to pass 2 dates with the format of `YYYY/MM/DD` my dates are all setup as `DD/MM/YYYY` how can I make isBetween() method recognise Australian date formats.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

My Code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

//checking to see if the user is 16 or 17 years old.
function parentGuardianRequired() {
    //todays date generated in a hidden field via php
    var signDate = $("#currentDate").val();
    //the users date of birth input
    var dateOfBirth = $("#dateOfBirth").val();

    //using moment to get the exact time of these dates while formatting the dates to AUS.
    var birthDate = moment(dateOfBirth, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var currentDate = moment(signDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");

    //subtracting 16 and 18 years from todays date to always do a valid age check
    ageSixteen = currentDate.subtract(16, "years");
    ageSeventeen = currentDate.subtract(18, "years");

    //checks if the user is between the age of 16 and 17
    if (birthDate.isBetween(ageSixteen, ageSeventeen)) {
        //you are 16 or 17 years old
        console.log("TRUE");           
    } else {
        //You are not 16 or 17 years old
        console.log("FALSE");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moment.isBetween()` works fine with two `moment` objects. The problem here is that you're using `subtract` twice on the same object, which just [mutates it each time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/). It does not return a new object. So your code should look more like this:

```
ageSixteen = moment(currentDate).subtract(16, "years");
ageSeventeen = moment(currentDate).subtract(18, "years");
```

Comment: Yet Another Example of why the MomentJS API *really* needs to move to [immutable objects](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1754).

Comment: I have added the js files im using in my code above, this still is returning false in my console log :/

Comment: if (birthDate.isBefore(ageSixteen) && birthDate.isAfter(ageSeventeen)) this seemed to work instead actually, but 02/08/1997 & 03/08/1997 returns false, but 04/08/1997 - 02/08/1999 returns true. when today is the 02/08/2015. Does that not mean that 02/08/1997 and 03/08/1997 should be true as well?

Comment: @c.had1990 I looked into it. Change your `if` to `if (birthDate.isBetween(ageSeventeen, ageSixteen))` instead. The later date has to come before the earlier date.

Comment: Oskar you legend!, worked as expected except I am still confused as to why it does not accept 02/08/1997 or 03/08/1997, is that because of leap years or?

Comment: @c.had1990 Someone born 02/08/1997 would be 18 years old. 03/08/1997 returns true for me though...

Comment: I know why, because when I pass my php date into the moment.js, it does not have the time, I am only passing the date, so it is not working accurately.